# Evaluation of $\lim_{x\to -2} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x - 6} + 2}{x+2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

> Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to -2} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x - 6} + 2}{x+2}$$

I tried to multiply by the conjugate expression but it didn't work.
 Wolfram Mathematica sais that it's a "DirectedInfinity". I don't understand that. 
 Please, explain me the steps of solution !

Comment: Does the edit reflect your question? MathJax is alot easier to read than Mathematica expressions. If it does, use l'Hospital to compute the limit.

Answer (score 5):

The conjugate works for the square-root because $(a+x)(a-x)=a^2-x^2$
For the cube-root, you need to use $(a+x)(a^2-ax+x^2)=a^3+x^3$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t^3=x-6.$  Then we have $t=\sqrt[3]{x-6}.$  This gives $t+2$ for the numerator and $t^3+8$ for the denominator.  Then we have 
$$\lim\limits_{t\to -2}\frac{t+2}{t^3+8}\\=\lim\limits_{t\to -2}\frac{t+2}{(t+2)(t^2-2t+4)}\\=\lim\limits_{t\to -2}\frac{1}{t^2-2t+4}\\=\frac{1}{12}$$